# GDB debugging in Linux _x86_64 command info

Tags: linux, gdb, x86-64, cpu-registers

I am trying to debug my program in linux with gdb.

i want to validate registers values of a particular frame in linux and for that i run two commands;
info reg and info frame

i found that the values shown by "info reg" command for different registers are different than  in this case the values showned for save registers for command "info frame". The registers rbp , rsp, rip are important for me.

What is the difference of these commands? and when it says "saved registers", what does this mean and at what location these registers are save?

Answer (score 1):

You want to switch to right frame before you do info reg. Then you will see that actually there is no difference between two.

Hope it helps.
Alex.